# Iterate over column in dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Would you please explain me how this works? Lines 5,6 and 8,9 don´t make much sense to me but I´m just starting with Python.

```
 1# Iterate over the column in dataframe
 2      for entry in col:
 3 
 4        # If entry is in cols_count, add 1
 5       if entry in cols_count.keys():
 6          cols_count[entry] += 1
 7     # Else add the entry to cols_count, set the value to 1
 8       else:
 9          cols_count[entry] = 1
 10   
 11      # Return the cols_count dictionary
 12     return cols_count
```

Comment: Indentation is essential in Python. Check yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cols_count` is a dictionary that counts how many times an `entry` appears.

Dictionary syntax to add an item to it goes like this:

```
d = {}
d["new_entry"] = value
```

What lines 5,6 and 8,9 do is check if there is already that entry in your dictionary and, if there is, increment `1` to the counter; if there is not, create that key and assign a value of `1` (because if the entry is not in the dict, then this is its first appearance).